# Enabling Laptop Bluetooth - setup.cpp (135) error

Tags: networking, bluetooth, drivers

I've been trying to enable Bluetooth on an Acer Aspire V3 running Win 7 Pro 64 bit. I've uninstalled and reinstalled drivers several times and tried cleaning out the registry. No luck, doesn't seem to recognize the hardware.

According to Acer, the laptop comes equipped with `"Acer Nplify 802.11a/g/n + BlueTooth 4.0"`, and another post I read said I had to update the `"Quallcomm Atheros WiFi Driver Installation"` program to enable Bluetooth. When I first attempted it asked me to locate folder containing layout.bin, then for folder containing 0x008xx. Found layout.bin in the driver folder, but not the second file.

Now, after cancelling out of that,  I can't modify or uninstall the Atheros WiFi Driver Installation program, I get and error referencing: SetupNew/setup.cpp (135). I have a screencap if it helps, but I can't post it because I'm a newbie.

Can't find much on this error, it seems to be a service or program holding on to it, but I've deleted/stopped/uninstalled any related services, programs or drivers I could find and tried to delete. Again, no luck.

Sorry about the long post, but I've been trying for hours and can't find anything on point for this online. Anyone have any ideas?